# Manifold whose universal covering is a sphere but which is not a space form? 

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry

Let $M^n$ be a smooth manifold whose universal cover is homeomorphic $\mathbb{S}^n$, are there examples where $M^n$ is not homeomorphic to a space form ?

The answer may vary if you replace homeomorphic by diffeomorphic, and I'm also interested in this question under this restriction.

I came to this question while reading surveys about sphere theorems, where the non simply-connected case is harder to get (while you already know that the universal cover is a sphere, you need more work to show it is actually a space-form).

Comment: Thanks to both Igors for your answers. I'm not familiar with these topics, so I'll have to dig a bit into these papers to understand. Does there exist a more elementary construction ?

Comment: The reference I suggest is a book, so this is probably as gentle as you can hope for. This was one of the guiding problems in topology for a couple of decades, so I don't think there is a really easy way of getting there.

Comment: Interestingly, the book Igor Rivin links to defines a space form to be "a manifold whose universal cover is a sphere" (on the first page of the introduction). I guess that here we mean "manifold which is the orbit space of a free action on a sphere".

Comment: There are other examples. You might like fake $RP^5$'s of nonnegative curvature of Grove-Ziller, see Theorem G in math.upenn.edu/~wziller/papers/groveziller.ps. Of course, the existence of fake $RP^5$'s was known to topologists long ago, but the above paper gives a geometric construction. Is that what you seek?

Comment: Are you interested when the universal cover of $M$ is an exotic sphere (and of course $M$ is smooth)?

Comment: Ok, thanks to all ! @Agol: why not ? even if I suspect that might be out of my reach...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are lots of fake lens spaces, and fake spherical space forms (search on these keywords). In particular, a construction of fake lens spaces is in chapter 12 of Milnor's  ["Whitehead torsion"](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-72/issue-3/Whitehead-torsion/bams/1183527946.full). Here are details:
start with any lens space $L$ with fundamental group of order different from 2,3,4, 6, so that its Whitehead group is infinite. Then there are infinitely many distict manifolds  that are h-cobordant to $L$. On the other hand, Corollary 12.13 implies that any h-cobordism between lens spaces is a product. (Of course, I assume dimension $\ge 5$ here).

Comment: This Page should contain much of what is known about classification of Fake Lens spaces: http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Fake_lens_spaces

Answer (score 11):

See [Davis-Milgram](http://www.indiana.edu/~jfdavis/books/Spherical_space_forms.pdf)

Answer (score 10):

The [geometrization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrization_conjecture) implies that 3-dimensional manifolds covered by $S^3$ are diffeomorphic to space forms.

There are examples of [Cappell-Shaneson](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=394709%20) and [Fintushel-Stern](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=607896)
of fake $\mathbb{RP}^4$s (in the Fintushel-Stern case, they actually
show there is a smooth exotic free involution of $S^4$).